# How to change Time of Day while Free-Roaming?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

I've heard you can change the Time of Day while playing the game. 
I would love to go collect chests in the night and such.

I've looked in some menus but I couldn't find the option to change said setting.

How can I change the Time of Day setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are **4 types** of Time Of Day in **Assassin's Creed: Unity**

You can choose between :

> - Morning
> - Afternoon
> - Dusk
> - Night

To change the actual Time Of Day follow these instructions:

> - Pause the Game (While roaming free in Paris);
> - Go to **'Options'**;
> - Go to **'Game Options'**;
> - Right below '**Brightness'** you have the **'Time of Day'** setting;
> - Change it to whatever setting you want.

To see these instructions in action watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOMum-qW-iI)

### **Note:**

- It may not work inside restricted areas.
- It does not work during main-missions.

Any update and I'll update this aswell.